# Algorithm to convert a large number (output of a hashing algorithm) into something easily compared visually by humans?

Tags: hashing

I'm looking for a way to help my users more easily compare the output of a fingerprinting algorithm (which is a very large number/byte array).

So instead of showing something like "8c0db1f40b6e4c1e268a5f3e2405278f" as the fingerprint, I'd rather show something like 'AT-BAD-HONEY-CAR-MOUSE' (obviously the underlying number of represented bits still needs to be the same as I cannot allow ambiguity, it's a fingerprint after all).

I'm not restricted to a textual representation, a (very small) image would also be fine (note: just using the bits as pixels in a b&w image does not count as "easily visually comparable" in my book). The only constraint on the algorithm would be that the final output does not need crazy amounts of screen real-estate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For textual representations, check out the [PGP word list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGP_word_list), [Diceware (as improved by EFF)](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2016/07/new-wordlists-random-passphrases), [S/KEY's word list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/KEY#Usability), and [BIP39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki).

For visual representations, check out [randomart](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/144702/9812); see also [here](https://superuser.com/q/22535/93541).

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that [identicons](http://identicon.net/) intend to solve. You may not have noticed, but SE uses identicons for their avatars. You may not have noticed, which says enough.

Comment: Since I want to compare fingerprints, distinct fingerprints also need to generate distinct icons/images. This is not the case for at least the SE identicons as they only represent a tiny number of bits.

Comment: You can always append an UUID.